# Read data from excel sheet and write in the same excel sheet

Tags: java, excel

I am looking for the program which will allow me to read from excel sheet (MS Office format) and then write in some new column ?
Apart from APACHE POI, is there any other library available in java to do this ?

I app

Answer (score 2):

[jexcelapi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) is more lightweight than POI, in our experience often a lot faster and with a simpler API.  It is however limited to the older xls format in its present state.

Comment: Thanks. Its very much simpler than POI.

Comment: Glad you like it.  If you feel this answer solves your problem please consider accepting the answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work